# stripe doesn't save the customer email and name in the dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to accept donations on my website and everything works great but it doesn't save the customer name and email however I am passing it in the billing_details. I think I need to pass it also on the server side,but it gives me this error (Undefined array key "email") when I used the post method '$email=$_POST['email'].. my question is how to pass the email to 'receipt_email' correctly.

```html
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('my secret key');


if(!isset($_SESSION['amount'])){
  header("Location: donations.php");

}
$amount = $_SESSION['amount'];


 $donation = $amount * 100; 

$email = $_POST['email'];

 $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  'email' => $email
));

$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => $donation,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  // Verify your integration in this guide by including this parameter
  'metadata' => ['integration_check' => 'accept_a_payment'],
      'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'receipt_email' => $email,
]);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
<body>
  
            <form  id="payment-form"   data-secret="<?= $intent->client_secret ?>">

                   <label>Card Holder Name</label> 
                <span id="card-holder-name-info" class="info"></span><br> 
                <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname"  required><br>

                <label>Email</label> 
                <span id="email-info" class="info"></span><br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  required><br>
              
                <label>Card Number</label> 
          <div id="card-element" >
            <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
          </div>

          <button type="submit" id="card-button" class="donate-btn yellow-btn">Donate</button>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
    
    var stripe = Stripe('my public key');
var elements = stripe.elements();
        
        
          var style = {
    base: {

      color: "#565556",
    }
  };

  var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
  card.mount("#card-element");

  card.on('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var fullname = document.getElementById('fullname');
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
 
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    
  stripe.confirmCardPayment(form.dataset.secret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card,
        billing_details: {
          name: fullname,
          email: email
        }
      }
    }).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
        alert(result.error.message);
      } else {
        // The payment has been processed!
        if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
          // Show a success message to your customer
        
          alert('The payment has been proccessed');
      window.location.replace("SuccessPage");
            


      }
    }
  });
});
        </script>
```

Comment: In your PHP code you're trying to access `$_POST['email']` which implies that this page is accessed by submitting a form on some other page, but then later you have an input field for an email address inside a `<form>` which doesn't make sense.  Are you collecting the email in a form being submitted to this page or are you attempting to collect the email on this page?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I got your point .. it really doesn't make sense. I want to collect the email on this page. maybe I have to access the email from this js part ` billing_details: {
          name: fullname,
          email: email
        }` but how??.

Comment: If you want to collect the email on this page you should add an `action` attribute to your `<form>` that points to another page where the form data will be sent to and replace your `window.location.replace("SuccessPage");` code with `form.submit()`.) Then you can access the email entered on this page in the code that handles the form submission.